# XQuery : get address/town from longitude/latitude with google maps API?

Tags: xml, api, maps, xquery

I know that I can get an XML file returning geographic information from this URL, by replacing [A] and [B] with latitude and longitude.

> http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?latlng=[A],[B]&sensor=true

Now what I want to know is how to call this URL from my .xqy file and simply get the values of  the address and town attributes in the XML file. Any idea ?

Comment: Is your question really, "How do I parse an XML file and extract values?"

Comment: That's what I want to know yeah.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the expath HTTP client in order to query this API:

```
import module namespace http = "http://expath.org/ns/http-client";

http:send-request(<http:request method="get" href="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?latlng=[A],[B]&amp;sensor=true" />)
```

You can try this example live at http://www.zorba-xquery.com/html/demo#SYTRRzV6oopDKuEs3hxUdj4lUts=

Answer (score 1):

Try to use geocoding service API with reverse geocoding.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding#ReverseGeocoding